# Дизассемблирование програмики

Tags: c#, дизассемблирование, reverse-engineering

**Доброго времени суток.**

Возникла у меня потребность, получить исходный код программки на шарпе, в универе дали задание написать прогу, и дали пример (.exe). Самому писать лень. Заюзал дизассемблер, что поставляется вместе со студией, не очень понравился резуальтат. Слишком много пальце-двежений нужно для создания проекта. Попробовал Dis#, уже лучше, выдало мне много кода и ничего лишнего, на радостях копи-пастнул все это дело, но возникла ожидаемая проблема с Гуем. Зато посмотрев код, понял что мне нужно то всего ничего пару значений переменных там поменять, да кнопочки в другие места расставить. В связи с чем прошу помощи:

- Как мне из .exe скомпиленным в более
     старой версии c# создать проект в c#
     2010 с возможностью мышкой потыкать
     вин форму?

Comment: Ну и зачем человека заминусовали? Лень это нормально, он же не просит сделать за него, просто ищет оптимальные варианты =)

Comment: думаю, что минусуют за лень. Ведь задание было не дизассемблировать, а самому написать.

Comment: Очевидно минусуют за нарушение правил форума: 

>Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за 
>деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием: форум не 
>является фриланс-биржей.

P.S. Соответствующую часть вопроса удалил

Comment: Нормальный вопрос (+1). 

Намного более жизненный и развивающий, чем *обычное (правильное)* обучение.

Comment: >то нормально что мой пост минусуется после правки? Или кому-то не нравится мой вопрос?

> Минусуйте дальше, а я поразвиваюсь :)

>Ребята, если не умеете чего-то ставьте +, а не -.

>Хотя я рад, привлекайте внимание :)

у вас, смотрю, нешуточный баттхерт разыгрался от минусов. 
З.Ы. я не минусовал, поскольку согласен с @avp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler) попробуйте

Comment: Как вариант - ILSpy.

Comment: Был еще бесплатный .NET Reflector, тоже годен.